# Running phpMyAdmin from its Git Repo?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

On all my servers, I run phpmyadmin using the STABLE branch of the phpmyadmin git repo (https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tree/STABLE). This allows for very easy updates/rollbacks.

On occasion, phpMyAdmin will notify me that there is a new stable version available and that I should upgrade, but the STABLE branch of the git repo is still at the previous version.

For instance, on 2014-05-13 there was a note that a new stable version (4.2.1) was available and as of 2014-05-14 19:00:00 UTC, the STABLE branch is still at 4.2.0.

Most of the time, once I notice the upgrade message, the STABLE branch is at that version, but on occasion there is a delay.

This brings up a couple questions:

- Is the STABLE branch the best branch to be running from?
- Is the delay from being notified that there is a new version to when it is available in the STABLE repo normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `STABLE` branch should always match the current release. That's the best branch to track if you wish to use git to stay updated but not on the development version (`master`, which is rarely actually broken but still not for general development use).

I have no idea why you saw a delay on the update -- if it happens again, you should probably contact the development team on the bug tracker about it.